# Error in redux when executing an action: Uncaught type error: cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Tags: javascript, redux

Just new to React. I guess It's a basic question but I can't get why the reducer doesn't get fired or update the state:

My HomeView.js:

```
     ....
          const { localeChange, counter, locale } = this.props
            return (
               <div>
                  <button onClick={() => increment(7)}>Increment</button>
              <input type='text' value = {counter}/>
               .....
            </div>
        )

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
      locale: state.locale,
      counter: state.counter
    })
    export default connect(mapStateToProps, {localeChange, increment})(HomeView)
```

My reducer (constant, action and reducer in the same file):

```
export const COUNTER_INCREMENT = 'COUNTER_INCREMENT'

export function increment (text) {
  return { type: COUNTER_INCREMENT, text }
}

export default function counterIncrement (state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'INCREMENT':
      return state + action.text
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

And finally my "parent" reducer:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { routeReducer as router } from 'react-router-redux'
import locale from './modules/locale'
import counter from './modules/counter'

export default combineReducers({
  locale,
  router,
  counter
})
```

What I understand:

In my state I have a field named counter (it's there using redux dev tools). 
When I click the button I dispatch increment action, so I really should dispatch an action like this:
{type: COUNTER_INCREMENT, text: 7}

However counterIncrement function (reducer) gets action as undefined: `Uncaught type error: cannot read property 'type' of undefined`. 
Any way I could debug this properly? I put a breakpoint in the reducer counterIncrement but doesn't get fired.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Redux validate that every action you trigger actually contains a type property.

My guess is that you're calling `dispatch()` with undefined. Your example code doesn't contains any dispatch calls, so I won't be able to help further - but my guess is that it'll be trivial to figure out. Either you call `dispatch()` with the wrong arguments, or your action creator doesn't return an object with a `type` property.

Side note (unrelated to your question), but your action creator type label doesn't match the one inside your reducer.

Comment: Uppps, yes. It was not in the code I uploaded, but I was writing import increment instead of import {increment}